# NodeJS/Express How to create 2 routes, similar path but different kind of parameters?

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I try to create two distinct routes:

1. /path/1234 (4 digits or less)
2. /path/123456789 (more than 4)

What I'm trying :

```
app.param(function (name) {
  return function(req,res,next,id) {
    //do some stuff here with id
    next();
  };
});
app.param('shortId', /[0-9]{0,4}/);
app.param('longId', /[0-9]{5,20}/);

app.get('/path/:shortId', function(req, res){
  res.send('ShortID:' + req.params.shortId);
});

app.get('/path/:longId', function(req, res){
  res.send('LongId:' + req.params.longId);
});
```

I always obtain a hit from the first path (shortId) even with a number longer than 4 digits.   Do someone has an idea of what I'm doing incorrectly here ?

Comment: Did you try just swapping them, checking for paths over 4 digits first.

Comment: Correct adeneo. But messy and cheap as said bduran. I need to use :shortId and :longId without having to care *so* much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Express match the first expression partially. It is not intuitive, but it still possible to obtain the wanted result by checking "manually" :

```
app.param(function (name,fn) {
  if (fn instanceof RegExp) {

    //fn is the regexp that I can use here
    return function(req,res,next,id) {

      if ( String(id).match(fn) ) {
        //do some stuff here with id
        next();
      }
      else {
        next('route');
      }
    };
  }
});
```

As said by bduran, the correct regexps are :

```
app.param('shortId', /^[0-9]{0,4}$/);
app.param('longId', /^[0-9]{5,20}$/);
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need express-params for this, you can just append a parenthesized regex directly to the parameter;

```
app.get('/path/:shortId([0-9]{0,4})', function(req, res){
  res.send('ShortID:' + req.params.shortId);
});

app.get('/path/:longId([0-9]{5,20})', function(req, res){
  res.send('LongId:' + req.params.longId);
});
```

EDIT:

To make express-params work, there are two things that cause problems in your existing example.

- As others have pointed out, you'll need to anchor your regular expressions using `/^...$/`, or the first expression will partially match the parameter and always be taken.
- Your first app.param call (where you pass the function) *always returns a function* which means overriding the other app.param calls to use the function for matching instead of the regex. Since the function always calls the parameterless `next()`, it always accepts all patterns.

Changing that would result in something like;

```
app.param(function (name, param) {
  if(name != 'veryshortid')           // Use this function for veryshortid only
    return;
  return function(req,res,next,id) {
    if(id.length > param) next('route');       // No match, skip
    else next();                               // Accept
  };
});

app.param('veryshortid', 1);
app.param('shortid', /^[0-9]{2,4}$/);
app.param('longid', /^[0-9]{5,20}$/);

app.get('/path/:veryshortid', function(req, res, next){
  res.send('VeryShortID:' + req.params.veryshortid);
});

app.get('/path/:shortid', function(req, res, next){
  res.send('ShortID:' + req.params.shortid);
});

app.get('/path/:longid', function(req, res, next){
  res.send('LongId:' + req.params.longid);
});
```

Comment: It works, but my goal is to use a lot of routes with :shortId and :longId without having to care too much about the regexp (let said a "one time for all" scheme). I also want to do some operations each time a route having a short/long id is called.

Comment: @PierreMaoui Updated my answer with how to make it work.

Comment: Why have you introduced veryshortid ? Have you seen my answer ? It seems more concise.

Comment: @PierreMaoui Just introduced it as a demo how to handle an ID entirely using the function callback syntax vs. the others via regex, and I honestly didn't see your answer where you did something similar before my edit :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because in Express logic the first regular expression match the `longId`, although partially. Be more restrictive and everything will go fine:

```
  app.param('shortId', /^[0-9]{0,4}$/);
  app.param('longId', /^[0-9]{5,20}$/);
```

Edited:

Also you can change the order in what you load the routes, but it's messy and cheap. Be restrictive ever, marking the beginning and the end of the regular expressions.

Comment: Actually I can't get this to work, although I agree it probably should.

Comment: I agree with Joachim on that. To change just the regexp doesn't work for me on my example.

Comment: I left the working code [here](https://gist.github.com/brunoduran/8109918#file-gistfile1-txt-L36-L61). It's what I used yesterday. It's a base express with some little changes. I have marked said modifications.